# How to implement Regions in Marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I am trying to learn `Marionette.js`.I started from [This](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/The-relationship-between-regions-and-layouts) link.While viewobject passing as a argument to the Regionobj. getting the following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'listenTo'
```

HTML code:

```
  <script src="lib/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/backbone-min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/handlebars.js"></script>    
  <script src="lib/backbone.marionette.js"></script> 
  <div id="firstDiv">
        <input id="firstButton" type="button" style="width:100px;height:50px;color:white;background-color:red;" value="Click Me!">
    </div>
```

Js.code

```
 var myView=Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
events:{
    "click #firstButton":"alertFunction"
},
alertFunction:function(){
    alert("Hi");
    console.log(this.el);
}
});
var myViewObj=new myView();
var myRegion = new Backbone.Marionette.Region({
el: "#firstDiv"
});
myRegion.show(myViewObj);
```

How can I fix this.

Comment: Have you included jQuery? It's a requirement for Backbone.

Comment: Also, I think Marionette regions require you to add a Marionette.View like an ItemView or CompositeView

Comment: @daleyjem I added `Marionette.js,jQuery.js,...` files. I don't know about different types of views.I just made Backbone.View .

Comment: Try what you have already, but change the `Backbone.View` to a `Backbone.Marionette.ItemView`

Comment: @daleyjem I modified my code with your code still getting the error. I modified my question let's check it and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, your view has no listenTo-method. This could be a backbone version issue. Which version of backbone do you use? Marionette requires min version 0.9.9 to work.

Comment: I am using `Backbone.js 0.9.2`, so Where Can I download that.